# How to cache .Count() queries in NHibernate.Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, caching

How do I cache the result of such a query:

```
Session.Query<Entity>().Count(e=> e.Property == someConstant)
```

I cannot place `Cacheable()` after it, and if I place it before the Count(), it would fetch the entire result set, wouldnt it?

Comment: Take a look at FromCache() method of LINQ.

Comment: Where exactly should this method be located?

Comment: Hmmm you could probably do something like `.Where(e => e.Property == someConstant).Cacheable().ToList()` and then just use the `.Count` property on the list. Or are you specifically trying to avoid caching the entity list?

Comment: Yes, because that would mean caching the entire table...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding Cacheable before the count **will cause the aggregate count results to be cached**. This can be seen by the SQL generated from my example below.

Domain and Mapping Code

```
public class Entity
{
    public virtual long id { get; set; }
    public virtual string name { get; set; }
}

public class EntityMap : ClassMap<Entity>
{
    public EntityMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.name);
        Cache.ReadOnly();
    }
}
```

The test code itself.

```
using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    session.Save(new Entity() { name = "Smith" });
    session.Save(new Entity() { name = "Smithers" });
    session.Save(new Entity() { name = "Smithery" });
    session.Save(new Entity() { name = "Smith" });
    tx.Commit();
}

String name_constant = "Smith";
using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    var result = session.Query<Entity>().Cacheable().Count(e => e.name == name_constant);
}

using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    var result = session.Query<Entity>().Cacheable().Count(e => e.name == name_constant);
}
```

The SQL generated from the above code can be seen below. As you can see, there are four `INSERT` statements, one for each `session.Save`. Whereas there is only one `SELECT` despite the two queries, each performing under a separate session. This is because the **result of the count has been cached by NHibernate**.

```
NHibernate: INSERT INTO [Entity] (name) VALUES (@p0); select SCOPE_IDENTITY();
@p0 = 'Smith' [Type: String (4000)]
NHibernate: INSERT INTO [Entity] (name) VALUES (@p0); select SCOPE_IDENTITY();
@p0 = 'Smithers' [Type: String (4000)]
NHibernate: INSERT INTO [Entity] (name) VALUES (@p0); select SCOPE_IDENTITY();
@p0 = 'Smithery' [Type: String (4000)]
NHibernate: INSERT INTO [Entity] (name) VALUES (@p0); select SCOPE_IDENTITY();
@p0 = 'Smith' [Type: String (4000)]
NHibernate: select cast(count(*) as INT) as col_0_0_ from [Entity] entity0_ 
            where entity0_.name=@p0;
@p0 = 'Smith' [Type: String (4000)]
```

The possible scenarios which will cause NHibernate to ignore `Cacheable` and go back to the DB are when:

1. The second level cache is not enabled in the session factory configuration.
2. The entity has not been marked as cacheable.

The only other scenario I know of that will cause NHibernate to perform two `SELECT` queries is when the entity has been evicted from the cache, either explicitly using `sessionFactory.Evict` or by the cached entity becoming expired between the two calls.